# Optaplanner not using other BinAvailabilty TO be Get Assign to an event

Tags: java, optaplanner

```
        @PlanningEntity
        public class BinAvailablity {
            private int id;
            private Interval interval;
            private Bin bin;
            private int roomMax;
            @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "binAvailablity")
            private List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
            private List<Interval> nonAvailablity;
        }


    public class Event {

        private int id;
        @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = IntervalAssigningListener.class,
                sources = {@PlanningVariableReference(variableName = "binAvailablity")})
        private Interval interval;//assignning listener variable
        private boolean isPinned;
        private TotalTime totalTime;
        @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "binAvailablities")
        private BinAvailablity binAvailablity;//plannig variable
        private List<Staff> staffList;
        private List<Equipment> equipmentList;
        private List<Interval> nonAvailability;}
```

My Configuration is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>
    <solutionClass>com.strategy.eagle.domains.optaplanner.EventBinAssignation</solutionClass>
    <entityClass>com.strategy.eagle.domains.optaplanner.Event</entityClass>
    <entityClass>com.strategy.eagle.domains.optaplanner.BinAvailablity</entityClass>
    <scoreDirectorFactory>
        <scoreDrl>Optaplanner/EventScheduling.drl</scoreDrl>
    </scoreDirectorFactory>
    <termination>
        <secondsSpentLimit>200</secondsSpentLimit>

        <bestScoreLimit>0hard/0soft</bestScoreLimit>


    </termination>


    <constructionHeuristic>
        <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
    </constructionHeuristic>
    <localSearch>

<!--       -->
        <localSearchType>HILL_CLIMBING</localSearchType>
    </localSearch>
</solver>
```

@PlanningSolution
public class EventBinAssignation {

```
private String id;

@PlanningScore
private HardSoftScore score;

@ProblemFactCollectionProperty
@ValueRangeProvider(id = "binAvailablities")
List<BinAvailablity> binAvailablities;

@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
List<Event> events;
```

}

I have  Created two entities with Event and BinAvailability . i need to assign Events to binAvailablity. but Optaplanner only  assign events to first binAvailability. No any other binAvailbility got used by Optaplanner to assign events the score got stuck but it does not use any other binavalilbity to assign events with some particular conditions .So please help.

Answer (score 1):

If OptaPlanner only assigns events to the first binAvailability, it's probably because your hard constraint doesn't match (in your scoreDrl). Turn on `TRACE` logging and look for the `score` numbers durings for each CH move.

Or put a System.out.println in the `then` of that constraint in the DRL.
Or migrate to ConstraintStreams and put a debugger break point in the `penalize()` matchWeighter lamdba.